# Using pam to configure ssh access via specific ip

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ip, pam

I am currently trying to configure a server and I want to allow every user with UID from 6000-6500 to ssh into my server ONLY if that ssh comes from an IP present in the file /etc/remote-hosts. I already have a way of putting on wantedUIDS the usernames of the users I want to configure this condition.

Currently I have the following on `sudo nano /etc/security/access.conf`:

```bsh
# This line works just fine
+ : @g67 asist : ALL

# This line is commented because I don't know what this will do or if this will work.
# + : pam_listfile.so item=user file=/etc/wantedUIDS : pam_listfile.so item=ip file=/etc/remote-hosts
```

Is this correct? Will this work? I don't know if I can use *pam file syntaxe* in this specific file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iptables` can track UIDs or GIDs (by name or numeric value) in the `OUTPUT` chain only. Therefore it will not work in the `INPUT` chain (by default). To accomplish this, I recommend you to create a user group (`employees` for example). Then add all your users that will be allowed SSH access, to the `employees` group.

Then edit `/etc/sshd_config` file, to something like this:

```
AllowGroups employees
```

You could add the IP addresses (whitelist) in this config file but it might look clumsy if you have a long list. Rather use `iptables`, in an automated fashion.

Next, hop over to iptables. Let's assume your IP whitelist contains ten (10) addresses (I will use dummy private IP addresses in this example):

```
$ cat whitelist.txt
10.0.0.0/24
10.2.1.3
192.168.10.0/24
192.168.22.25
172.16.4.1
172.17.80.0/26
192.168.80.4/30
10.10.10.0/26
192.168.1.1
172.20.20.4
```

We can add all these IP addresses to iptables using a simple bash script

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat whitelist.txt)
do 
iptables -I INPUT -s $i -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
done
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

That's all you need. You can now test for functionality. If all goes well, consider saving the iptables rules.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I did not notice that I could put a complete subnet using /24 and it would accept it...